# Selenium, Cucumber and Java - browser init problems

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm using a framework for my Cucumber/Selenium test projects, located in a separate project.

While upgrading to the later versions of the fremework, with selenium 4.x and Cucumber 7.x, I'm running into problems with one of my projects. The other ones does not have the problem.

In my Hooks.java file, I have this line in the beforeAll() method:

```
try {
  (*) Browser.init(getBrowserConfig(), Collections.singletonList("--remote-allow-origins=*"));
} catch (MalformedURLException | RuntimeException e) {
  log.error("Browser configuration failed");
  unexpectedShutdown("Error configuring browser, stopping  test run");
}
```

This calls the following method in my Browser.java file in my framework project:

```
public static void init(BrowserConfig browserConfig, List<String> chromeOptionsParameters) throws MalformedURLException {
  webAppTeknologi = browserConfig.getWebAppTeknologi();
  String seleniumGridUrl = browserConfig.getSeleniumGridAdresse();
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(seleniumGridUrl)) {
    int i = 0;

    while(i <= 5) {
      try {
        opprettEksternBrowser(browserConfig.getNettleserType(), new URL(seleniumGridUrl));
        break;
      } catch (UnreachableBrowserException var7) {
        log.debug(String.format("Klarte ikke starte browser mot %s på forsøk nr %s. Venter 10 s", seleniumGridUrl, i));

        try {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10L);
        } catch (InterruptedException var6) {
          var6.printStackTrace();
        }

        ++i;
      }
    }
  } else {
    opprettLokalBrowser(browserConfig.getNettleserType(), chromeOptionsParameters);
  }
    setBrowserTimeouts(20, 0, 30);
}
```

I can paste more code if necessary.

When I try running a test, ie. the whole shabang of compiled and run, I get this error:

```
Step failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap     com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object,    java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:70)
at no.husbanken.e2e.rammeverk.selenium.Browser.opprettLokalBrowser(Browser.java:81)
at no.husbanken.e2e.rammeverk.selenium.Browser.init(Browser.java:64)
at e2e.support.Hooks.beforeAll(Hooks.java:66)
at e2e.support.Hooks.beforeEachScenario(Hooks.java:88)
```

The line it points to in Hooks.beforeAll() - 66 - is the one marked with (*) in the code above.

Any ideas?